# How to perform inline editing in Codeigniter PHP using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I saw an example in native PHP which allows inline editing or records and also updates them.
[PHP Inline Editing](http://phppot.com/php/php-mysql-inline-editing-using-jquery-ajax/) Now as per this code i have a ajax function which calls the update file whenever the content is updated below is the script :

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
    function showEdit(editableObj) {
        $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF");
    } 

    function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
        $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(<?php echo site_url('img/loaderIcon.gif');?>loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo(site_url('Inlinedit/updateDb'));?>",
            type: "POST",
            data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
            success: function(data){
                $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
            }        
       });
    }
    </script>
```

THe Model :

```
public function inline( $column, $editval, $id )
        {
            $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users set $column = $editval WHERE  id=$id");
        }
```

the Controller:

```
<?php
```

class Inlinedit extends Admin_Controller   {

```
 public function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct(); 
 }


      public function updateDb()
      {
             $column = $this->input->post('column');
             $editval = $this->input->post('editval');
             $id = $this->input->post('id');

             $this->load->model('user_m');                     
             $this->user_m->inline( $column, $editval, $id );

             return;
      }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should understand you cant **call model function bypassing controller**. for that what you have to do is

1. Create a new method in controller.(One time use)
2. Inside that method just use method calling your model.

ex
**In controller**

```
public function just_a_method()
{
    $this->Model_name->inline();/just call method
}
```

and in view

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url()?>controller/just_a_method",
```

Comment: So for ajax i must write <?php echo base_url('inlinedit/updateDb');?>

Comment: so your controller name is `inlinedit` and create new function for ajax call

Comment: new function for ajax call ? i have a function in my header file  function saveToDatabase as shown in question code

Comment: if you have exist one you can use it.but follow my way

Comment: i did'nt understood , i have a controller fine, load a model in model i have the update query. Now the ajax function! where it should be in my view file or the header file so i can access it everywhere?

Comment: what is common use on that. if header is common for all use on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89038/discussion-between-rajan-and-abdulla).

Comment: Thanks Man For Your Efforts and Time :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update the models directly.
Create a controller for updating code.

```
<?php
   class InlineEditController extends BaseController
   {
          public function updateDb()
          {
                 $column = $this->input->post('column');
                 $editval = $this->input->post('editval');
                 $id = $this->input->post('id');

                 $this->load->model('user_m');                     
                 $this->user_m->inline( $column, $editval, $id );

                 return;
          }
   }
```

> and in the ajax use `<?php echo(site_url('InlineEdit/updateDb'));?>`

Model must be

```
public function inline( $column, $editval, $id )
{
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users set $column = $editval WHERE  id=$id");
}
```

Comment: Hey your code is logical but some how my ajax code is not working i mean the data is not getting updated i am updating the question code please check

Comment: did you checked if database is returning any error? I think there may not be an issue related to code now.

Comment: should i be placing the ajax function in header file?  or maybe the ajax is not being loaded :(

Comment: better you should add to in `$(document).ready(function(){ *your functions* });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89040/discussion-between-rajan-and-php-sheep).

Comment: see i have a user controller which fetches all the records using User_m model and shows the records in view folder user/index 
now do i have to make a separate controller ? 
or could i just write the updateDb method in my users controller?